# AVPlayer plays audio but video freezes

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avplayer

I have two `UIViewControllers` each with an `AVPlayer` that are supposed to play a video file when they are pushed into a `UINavigationController`:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    videoView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myVideo" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];

    AVPlayerLayer *foregroundLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
    self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
    foregroundLayer.frame = self.view.frame;
    foregroundLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

    [videoView.layer addSublayer:foregroundLayer];

    [self.view addSubview:videoView];

    self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[self.avPlayer currentItem]];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [self.avPlayer play];
}

-(void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]
}
```

The first time I push any of the `UIViewControllers` the playback works well. But after that, if I push any of them again the sound plays but the video freezes.

I've tried using a `MPMoviePlayerViewController` but the behavior is the same. Any thoughts?

Comment: Strange! I do the same with you. It works well. Both the sound and the video play. I read from this article:http://www.jacopretorius.net/2013/02/playing-video-in-ios.html